# google play shows -- downloads of my apk

Tags: android, download, google-play

I uploaded my apk about 48h ago and it must have about 400 downloads already but when I check my account it shows a Line on downloads even that I have about 50 scores..

(I can't post images till 10 rep..)
http://postimg.org/image/euzqg3kll/

when is it gonna get updated?

Comment: Is this the correct url that you wanted to show to us?

Comment: wait for a while, the starts will keep updating but it´s slow. You´ll see new numbers each 24 hours with no changes but first week it took me something like 4 days until first data came out. It´s a weird behaviour but it´s like that.

Comment: thanks eduyayo, and skizo, yes, this is, I just wanted to show that scores are updated every second but downloads aren't..

Comment: 400 downloads in 48 hours is amazing. Do you mind telling us what promotion methods did you use to get these results? Thanks

Comment: is it a joke andreas? If you were talking seriously, it was telling it to friends and sending broadcasts on facebook, instagram, twitter, whatsapp and telling my best friends to do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time you post an app it takes like 3 days to start counting visits